# Is there a way to pad a char array that contains formatted elements using sprintf?

Tags: c++, c

So I'm using sprintf to produce a formatted char[] for displaying the date.

```
sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
```

But I would also like to have the entire result right-padded with spaces for a total length of 20 characters. I've tried:

```
sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%-20s", lcdContent_line1);
```

But that just blows out the whole thing. Is there a way to compose the format string so that I can right pad this entire thing?

EDIT:

LOLOL simple solution:

```
memset(lcdContent_line1, 0, 20);
sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%-19s", lcdContent_line1);
```

Turns out I was overrunning the buffer with %-20s since that was the entire length, you have to leave room for the 0. >.<

EDIT 2:

Thanks to @chux for pointing out that this is, in fact, a terrible solution that has no right to work as well as it does. Undefined behavior hell is a real place where you will be sent at the first sign of defiance.

Comment: What is the point of right-padding a line with spaces - you would not be able to see them?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Most likely this will have something else concatenated after it. Notice that there's no newline.

Comment: The question is tagged C++, so why are you using C style formatting via `sprintf()` at all, and not C++ style formatting via `std::ostream`, such as `std::ostringstream`? You can pad and align the output using the [`std::setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) stream manipulators.

Comment: [Live Demo for C++](https://ideone.com/EpihqE)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: TBH, even in C++ I'd use `sprintf` (actually, my wrapper which handles the buffer by itself and returns an `std::string`), way more concise and easier to read, without all those stupid formatters (and the time lost to check which is sticky and which is not) in the way. Then to pad right I'd just call `.resize(20, ' ')`. `oss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << month << "/" << std::setw(2) << day << "/" << std::setw(4) << year;` - seriously? I cannot even see that we are talking about a date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format without parsing through a row of line noise.

Comment: @MatteoItalia perhaps, but the C++ way is much safer. Too many times, people get the `printf` format string wrong (case in point).

Comment: `sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%-19s", lcdContent_line1);` has the source and destination overlap.  This is _undefined behavior_ and a wrong solution.  Better to post your answer as an answer below than appending to the question.  The question needs a bit more detail and your answer is wrong.  DV until repaired.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: [that's why you have to domesticate it a bit...](https://ideone.com/5VDW4T)

Comment: @MatteoItalia C++11 and later have [`std::put_time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time), which is closer to the `printf` functionality without losing safety.  I updated [my demo](https://ideone.com/EpihqE) to show it

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that's nice and everything for this use case, but I still find absurd that C++ still doesn't have a type-safe, placeholder-based formatting straight in the standard.

Comment: @MatteoItalia feel free to write your own implementation and submit it to the C++ committee for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to do it in a single step; your second example is wrong because input and output overlap (actually, they are the same string), and this is definitely not allowed.

You may fix it by using a separate buffer and let an `sprintf` pad your string, or you may come up with more clever stuff, such as

```
for(int i = sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
    i < 20; ++i) lcdContent_line1[i] = ' ';
lcdContent_line1[20] = 0;
```

to pad it inplace.

But honestly, in this case the easiest solution is probably

```
sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%02d/%02d/%04d          ", month, day, year);
```

Answer (score 4):

My proposal

```
int whatYouWant = 10 circa about;
sprintf(lcdContent_line1, "%02d/%02d/%04d%*c", month, day, year, whatYouWant, ' ');
```

Update: Link to documentation: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf
and here go to example

```
printf("%*d", width, num);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 10 circa about. Could you clarify this solution? What does the %*c formatting do? Why are their 5 arguments but only 4 format placeholders?

Comment: 1. "circa" - ... count characters You require. 2. https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf and find here `%*` example. Star is very interesting (gets one more parameters than simple arguments)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of Jacek Cz, which is based on a fixed size date format, you could use `%n` to get the number of characters of a non-fixed format. See the following code demonstrating this on the example of a single integral value with variable length in the output:

```
int main() {

    char x[50];
    int nrOfChars=0;
    sprintf(x,"%d%n",123567,&nrOfChars);
    sprintf(x+nrOfChars,"%*c|",20-nrOfChars,' ');

    printf("012345678901234567890123456789\n");
    printf("%s\n",x);
}
```

Output:

```
012345678901234567890123456789
123567              |
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` conveniently returns "the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings)." (Found in `man sprintf` although roughly the same wording appears in the C standard.)

So:

```
char lcdContent_line1[40]; /* Or whatever you need */
/* Use snprintf just in case */
int printed = snprintf(lcdContent_line1, sizeof(lcdContent), 
                       "%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
if (printed >= 0 && printed < 20)
  sprintf(lcdContent_line1 + printed, "%*s", 20 - printed, "");
```